# Powershell method to retrieve ALL Microsoft Teams Apps

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Have been given a job to audit our Microsoft Teams Apps on one of our Tenants (Allowed / Blocked / Blocked Org Wide). Am aware I can get an apps list through a simple PNP Powershell call like this:

Get-TeamsApp | Out-GridView

Which returns the Id, DisplayName and DistributionMethod of these apps:
Calling, Teams, Saved, Files, Assignments, Chat, Search, Calendar, Power Automate, OneNote, SharePoint, Azure DevOps Server, News, Edu PLC Notebook, Share conversation, Share to Teams, Shifts, Bookings, Bing News, Weather, Help, Insights, Edu PLC Notes, Walkie Talkie, Advisor for Teams, Grades, Edu Class Notes, Edu Staff Notes, Broadcast QnA, Forms, Stocks, Help, Whiteboard, Edu Class Notebook, PowerApps, Outgoing Webhook, Places, Edu Staff Notebook, Flow, SharePoint News, Maps, Test, Excel, PDF, PowerPoint, Visio, Word, Document Library, OneNote (Legacy), Planner, Power BI, Azure DevOps, Website, Wiki, Stream, Images, Praise, Power BI, Wikipedia Search, Azure Boards, Dynamics 365, Communities, Azure Pipelines, Azure AD Notifications, Azure Repos
However, that only returns a few of the apps (seemingly the ones available on the store to deployed Teams), not all the apps listed in https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps

Can anyone please tell me how I can extract the list that appears on https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps using Powershell?

Thanks in advance!

G

Comment: Questions about how to manage MS Teams is off-topic at SO, since it's not about programming. Try SuperUser or ServerFault instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please find graph api call method in below method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

and
powershell cmdlets available in below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamsapp?view=teams-ps

both not providing the allow and blocked list of apps. you will get those details in UI